# Push Notification in UWP

Tags: push-notification, uwp

I am trying to find the solutions for the Push Notification from server, but I am not getting success. Can anyone help me to code for the Push Notification in Application and Server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide a specific page. Take a look at the [instructions and samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-choosing-a-notification-delivery-method).

The toast can create a number of actions. One of the actions is to launch your app in the foreground passing the arguments value. Your app can then do whatever it wants when it is activated since it can evaluate the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification/) is a great resource to get you started.

You should know though that before asking questions on Stack Overflow you should do a minimum or research and come with a specific question based on what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some more information to the [Microsoft Azure Notification Hubs for Windows Store Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification/)

I definitely recommend this one but I will explain why.
It is really easy to configure Notification Hub to send notifications from you backedn. When you revise above article you will see that you have to implement only few steps to make it works.
This is the simple code to send notification from your backend:

```
private static async void SendNotificationAsync()
{
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<connection string with full access>", "<hub name>");
var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">Hello from a .NET App!</text></binding></visual></toast>";
await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
}
```

Few lines and it's ready.
I also recommend this one because you can easily integrate this with other platforms like Android or iOS.
There is also very good documentation if you would like to extend your backend.
Here is good article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/azure/dn743807.aspx

If you have any questions to that, please add comment and I hope that this will help you.